# Global name user_id not defined in Django?

Tags: django

I have a login and query function like this:

```
def login_backend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        username1 = ''.join(username)
        password = request.POST['password']
        password = ''.join(password)
        password1 = hashlib.sha1(password).hexdigest()
        user = authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)
        global user_id 
        user_id = request.user.id
        if user is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_backend/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def show_files(request):
    b = File.objects.get(id=user_id) #Get the user id from session .delete() to use delete
    return render_to_response('index.html',  {'result': b}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception Type: NameError at /overview/
Exception Value: global name 'user_id' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `global user_id` does not declare a global variable. It just tell python that this variable is a global scope variable. I don't like that you are trying to store `user_id` in global variable. Always access the current user id using `request.user.id` in your view.

This piece of code in your `log_backend` view is also wrong:

```
global user_id 
user_id = request.user.id # user does not exists in the request because user was trying to logged in
```

Just remove it you don't need it. Also you need to do `login(request, user)` after `authenticate` because `authenticate` function is just to check username and password supplied is correct.

```
user = authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)
login(request, user)
```

Comment: Where you are getting `None` value? Please be more specific.

Comment: Like you said I get the id of user once they are logged in so I using request.user.id in show_files as: user_id=request.user.id and using in template index.html as {{ user_id }} which returns None value.

Comment: have you passed the `user_id` in the context to template?

Comment: Yes I did. {'user_id': user_id} and called it in template.

Comment: See my updated answer you are missing `login(request, user)` in your `login_backend` function after `authenticate`.

Comment: Error -->'GalaxyUser' object has no attribute 'backend':: backend in my file_name where i Have views and GalaxyUser is the model name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22695/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-user1881957)

Comment: Hi Aamir. You are not there!